# Angular - run block vs bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular

I want to upgrade an angular 1.5 application to angular 2. Starting to sequentially migrate the code, I am trying to set it up as a hybrid, as described in the [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#sts=Bootstrapping%20Hybrid%20Angular%201+2%20Applications).
However, I started learning angular with 2.0 beta, so I am not quite familiar with the angular 1.x world.

What does the `app.run()` block do in comparison to `angular.bootstrap()`?
From the docs:

**Run blocks**

> get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application.

**angular.bootstrap**

> Use this function to manually start up angular application.

Someone can explain the difference?

The current app uses `app.run(require('run.js'))` and the `ng-app="myApp"` directive so I can simply use `upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp'])` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The `run` block is an optional function which is equivalent to:

- `dojo/domReady!` in Dojo
- `$.ready` in jQuery
- `connectedCallback` in Web Components
- `componentWillMount` in react.js
- `oncreate` in mithril.js
- `onReady` in Ext.js
- `ko.components.register` in knockout.js

whereas `bootstrap` is a required binding between the DOM and the framework(but is implicitly bound via the `ng-app` declaration by default) which is equivalent to:

- `<xsl:stylesheet>` in XSLT
- `<svg>` in SVG
- `<canvas>` in HTML5 Canvas
- `<object>` in Flash
- `new Vue` in vue.js

**References**

- [Custom Elements - Web Components | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements)
- [dojo/domReady! - The Dojo Toolkit - Reference Guide](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/domReady.html#dojo-domready)
- [XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/)
- [jQuery.ready | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ready/)
- [Document Structure - SVG 1.1 (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html)
- [The Vue Instance - Vue.js 2.0](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)
- [The Vue Instance - vue.js 1.0](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html)
- [Lifecycle Methods: oncreate - mithril.js](https://mithril.js.org/lifecycle-methods.html#oncreate)
- [onReady: Ext JS 6.2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.html#method-onReady)
- [Apply tag attributes in Adobe Flash Professional](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html)
- [Comparing Web Components and React, part one: Custom Elements and React lifecycle hooks #usetheplatform / blog unblock](https://andywalpole.me/blog/148724/comparing-web-components-react-part-one-custom-elements-react-lifecycle-hooks-usetheplatform)
- [Tutorial: Create reusable and future-proof UI components with Custom Elements v1 and Web Components](https://onsen.io/blog/create-reusable-future-proof-ui-components-with-custom-elements-v1-web-components/)
- [Custom Elements That Work Anywhere](http://robdodson.me/interoperable-custom-elements/)
- [Introducing Custom Elements | WebKit](https://webkit.org/blog/7027/introducing-custom-elements/)
- [Building Custom Elements That Work With AngularJS 1.x and Angular](https://steele.blue/custom-elements-angularjs/)
- [Integrating MDC-Web into Frameworks - Material Components for the Web](https://material.io/components/web/docs/framework-integration/)
- [Knockout : Component loaders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html)